# How can I prevent my Apple Magic Mouse from becoming disconnected while using it on a laptop running Windows 7?

Tags: windows-7, mouse, bluetooth

I have an unused Apple Magic Mouse, so I paired it with a Dell Latitude E5530 running Windows 7. The connection is unstable at best. I have periods of connectedness (sometimes lasting an hour or more) and periods of time when the mouse is "connected" and "authenticated" per the mouse Properties sheet, but does not move or respond at all.

The remedy in most cases where the bluetooth connection is severed is to fire up the Bluetooth Devices window and open the Properties sheet of the mouse, then choose the Services tab, where the Properties sheet then does a quick survey of all the services this particular Bluetooth device can perform.

It seems that this "survey" of sorts somehow rekindles the connection between the Magic Mouse and the laptop.

Can anyone explain why this happens, how to fix it, or otherwise have any method that works for them to make the connection more reliable? I've updated my Bluetooth drivers to the latest ones, so I am at a loss.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the answer in [this post](http://sherylcanter.com/wordpress/2010/01/bluetooth-mouse-losing-connection-no-more/) by Sheryl Canter.

Essentially:

1. Ensure the Bluetooth service starts automatically on startup
2. Ensure that Bluetooth power management is set to NOT let the computer turn off the Bluetooth device in order to save power.

Complete details can be found at the link above.